# Why is the stonesense command not found?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

According to [this](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=139553.0) post about the latest version of DFHack, stonesense is one of the example commands. However, after downloading that version of DFHack, typing stonesense into the console just says that `stonesense is not a recognized command`. Is this just outdated documentation or is there something I'm not doing?

Comment: The page you linked to says you have to download Stonesense separately.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg If this solved your issue, could you please close the question?

Answer (score 1):

Stonsense wasn't bundled by default with old versions of DFHack due to bugs, but it is now. Download the [latest version](https://github.com/DFHack/dfhack/releases/tag/0.40.19-r1) .40.19r1 which should include Stonesense on every OS.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that Stonesense is not compiled.

If you compiled DFHack yourself, check the compilation options with ccmake